# Creating a custom FTPS connection manager

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to create my own FTPS class for handling connections based on a sealed class called "[FtpClientConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.ftpclientconnection.aspx)" but I'm having trouble understanding how to set things up. I used JetBrains dotPeek to see code MS used for the class constructor and I see:

```
public FtpClientConnection(object unmanagedObject)
{
  try
  {
    this.m_ftpClientConn = unmanagedObject as IDTSFtpClientConnection100;
    this.m_persistImpl = new PersistImpl(unmanagedObject as IDTSPersist100);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ExceptionWrapper.Wrap(ex);
  }
}
```

From here I'm trying to understand how I can use `FtpWebRequest` to handle the same methods in this class and make my own `FtpsClientConnection` class. My first go at this is something like:

```
public FtpClientConnection(object unmanagedObject)
    {
      try
      {
        this.m_ftpClientConn = FtpWebRequest as IDTSFtpClientConnection100;
        this.m_persistImpl = new PersistImpl(unmanagedObject as IDTSPersist100);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ExceptionWrapper.Wrap(ex);
      }
    }
```

Any direction in understanding how to setup this class so that it can be as such would be appreciated.

Comment: MS has fine samples available on [codeplex](https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the FTPClientConnect... Instead could you use the nugget package Renci.SshNet?

Here is a very simple example of using it to list all the files from a server running ftps.

```
            using (var sftp = new SftpClient(sFTPConfig.SFTPFileServer, sFTPConfig.SFTPFileUser, sFTPConfig.SFTPFilePassword))
            {

                sftp.Connect();
                var files = sftp.ListDirectory(sFTPConfig.RemotePath);

           }
```

Comment: oh yea, library seems like it would be much simpler to implement. thanks!

Comment: except that it seems to target NET 3.5 and 4 --- i'm working with 2.0, unfortunately.

Comment: Total bummer... yeah this library is only for .net 3.5 and 4.0

Comment: Awesome glad you found a solution.